# How to export a table as a png file?

Tags: list, save, png, stata

I am using the `list` command in Stata and the output is a table. However, I cannot find how to save the output of the `list` command as a png or jpeg file (since this is not a graph and is not saved).

Code leading to the stata output:

`list var1 var2, noobs noheader fvall`

I would like to save this output.

I could not find a way to do this.

Comment: I don't think there is a direct Stata way to do this. If you want to show Stata output in a presentation, there are plenty of ways to do that.

Comment: Would a screenshot work?

Comment: What OS are you using? There are ways to do this by going through the shell. You can also make a LaTeX table and insert that into a document.

Comment: I need around 1000 of these images so it would be difficult to have screen shots manually. That is why I am interested in doing it in a more programmed way. I am using Microsoft. I am also open to other program suggestions if there are any (like matlab or jupyter notebook). thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather clumsy way to do this on a Mac. There are most likely Windows equivalents of the pdflatex and sips shell commands, but I don't have a Windows machine to play with. You will also need to install LaTeX. The output won't look exactly like what you see in Stata, but it may be good enough for your purpose.

First, I used Roy Wada's dataout to make a LaTex table of the data. You can install that from SSC. Then I used pdftolatex to compile that table into a PDF file. I then converted that PDF file to PNG with sips.

Here's the code:

```
sysuse auto, clear
list make price in 1/10, noobs noheader fvall
keep make price 
keep in 1/10
dataout, save(data_list) tex replace
!pdflatex data_list.tex
!open data_list.pdf
!convert data_list.pdf data_list.png
!sips -s format png data_list.pdf --out data_list.png
!open data_list.png
```